# Set page template automatically according to parent slug

Tags: page-template

I've seen several similar topics on this forum but still unable to come to a solution.

I have a parent slug named "en".  I named its template as "page-en.php".  Every time when I make a child page having "en" as the parent, I want to apply the description on "page-en.php" to it.  There are many children.

I've been successful when it's only **www.SITE.com/en/** but when there is a child it's not working out (e.g. **www.SITE.com/en/child**), and instead showing a reflection from "page.php", which is not desired.

Here are what I want to avoid:

*Using translation plug-ins
*Differentiating with id as it's pain to have separate templates for each id

These are "page" and not "post".

Any insight is deeply appreciated.

Hiro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the hierarchy and load a specific page template via the `page_template` filter.

The fastest way is to identify the parent page by ID:

```
function wpd_page_template_filter( $template ){
    $page = get_queried_object();
    if( 42 == $page->post_parent ){ // en page has ID of 42
        $template = locate_template( 'page-en.php' );
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpd_page_template_filter' );
```

or you can also identify it by slug with an extra step:

```
function wpd_page_template_filter( $template ){
    $page = get_queried_object();
    $parent_slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', $page->post_parent );
    if( 'en' == $parent_slug ){
        $template = locate_template( 'page-en.php' );
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpd_page_template_filter' );
```

If your page is a grandchild or lower, you can get the topmost parent with the [`get_ancestors`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/) function

Comment: It worked, thank you so much!!  I've been asking all over without a success, but finally I did it!  Really appreciate it.